# Cell format (setWrap) when Form submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've set up a form to send results to a spreadsheet.  Most the results are paragraph text. As each new row is added the default is no wrapping despite what formatting may have been applied to the column.

Is there a way to run a script to change the format of the new cells to wrap as each new entry is submitted. Not sure how this should be written.. should it be **onedit, onformsubmit**...and will **setwrap** work. Does anyone have an example of this?  complete newbie.

Answer (score 1):

function onFormSubmit(e) { e.range.setWrap(true); }

Add a trigger to run on form submit

Comment: Answer is correct, but probably overly concise for a 'complete newbie'. 
`function FormSubmitTasks() {

  // Setup sheet references
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  
  // Format cells in new row. 
  var CommentsCell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),15);
  CommentsCell.setWrap(true);
  var SchoolCell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),16);
  SchoolCell.setWrap(true);
` 
      return
  }`